# Is mankind correctly used as 3rd person singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-vs-plural

Is "mankind" used correctly as 3rd person singular? Or 3rd person plural?

For example:  "Mankind knows" or "mankind know"?

Comment: *mankind* is uncountable, so you say *mandkind knows.*

Comment: It acts singular like other uncountable nouns. *Chemistry is hard*, for example.

Comment: @StuW Not all uncountables are singular... Wear some **clothes**, please.

Comment: Good one! I should have included "most."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always used as a singular noun. The word encompasses all of humankind as a unitary whole.